# Homepage activity - android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 activities, 1 for registeration and 1 for the main page of my application.
Now in order to choose between them I have to create another activity that checks some details and decides to which activite to go.
The problem is that after I choose the main page activity I have 2 activities on the background and when I quit my app I have another empty page.
The page thats check those things don't need a graphical layout.. how can I solve this case?
btw if you have a better suggestion for my title let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our application we tackle similar problem differently. Our approach would work like that for your case:

1. Always try to launch Main Page.
2. At the startup of Main Page check "*some details*" and if you decide that Registration needs to be launched - do that.
3. When you want to go from Registration to Main Page, just finish RegistrationActivity and you'll go back to Main Page.

This way back button on the Main Page won't take you to the Registration and you won't see any "*empty page*".